# Django search_fields foreign key not working as expected

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using django_rest_api_framework. I need to search foreignkey. My search field is "customer_id"

views.py file

```
class DebtListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DebtCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwner]

    filter_backends = [SearchFilter]
    list_display = ('customer_id',)
    search_fields = ["customer_id__id"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Debt.objects.filter()
        return queryset
```

serializers.py file

```
class DebtCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Debt
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'customer', 'debtKey', 'created_userKey', 'total_Debt', 'received_Amount',
                  'payment_Date', 'description', ]
```

models.py

```
class Debt(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0,
                             blank=False)    
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False,
                                 related_name='customer')  
    debtKey = models.UUIDField(editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4,
                               blank=False)
    created_userKey = models.UUIDField(editable=False,
                                       default=uuid.uuid4)
    total_Debt = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    received_Amount = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    payment_Date = models.DateField(blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    created_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    modified_Date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your field is called `customer`, not `customer_id`.

Also, I think the default `DjangoFilterBackend` might be more appropriate than a `SearchFilter`, because a `SearchFilter` is meant for string search query, for instance on the name of a customer.

I think you copied (some of) this code from an Admin class, because list_display doesn't do anything on APIViews either.

Change your views.py to:

```
class DebtListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DebtCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsOwner]

    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ["customer__id"]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Debt.objects.filter()
        return queryset
```

One other thing I notice is that you use mixed-case variables like `payment_Date`, `created_userKey` and `debtKey`. The python naming convention for variables is only an underscore, no capitalisation, so you should consider changing that to `payment_date`, `created_user_key`, and `debt_key`.